proto can not deserialize field if that is value 0
We serialize the proto file (proto3) and send it via nats as follows.
We subscribe and receive the data from the sent side, we convert this data to json with message to json as follows.
std::string req_message_str;  
google::protobuf::util::MessageToJsonString(deserialized_set_ru_conf, &req_message_str);  
std::cout<<req_message_str<<std::endl;

We see that the default values are not serialized and sent in the incoming data, but we also have the following observation:
If the parameter is optional, even though it has a default value, it is serialized and the data comes to us, but we use a non-optional parameter.
We want to serialize and send the parameter and see that data after the message to json. Can you help me with this?
I want to see non-optional fields in JSON. Maybe I needed to pass an argument like JsonPrintOptions, but I'm not sure.

If you're not sure, then why haven't you tried it? Docs suggest you're on the right track, with their "bool JsonPrintOptions::always_print_primitive_fields -- Whether to always print primitive fields. -- By default proto3 primitive fields with default values will be omitted in JSON output. For example, an int32 field set to 0 will be omitted. Set this flag to true will override the default behavior and print primitive fields regardless of their values."

You don't include the relevant part of the .proto, but this sounds like "presence tracking". Basically, originally in proto3, the only option was "implicit zero defaults", i.e. if it is zero: it isn't sent; that's what you get if you use:
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    int32 id = 1;
}

However, a while later, "presence tracking" was added to proto3 as an opt-in feature, which means it tracks whether a value is explicitly assigned. This means that if a field is explicitly assigned a value including zero: it is serialized. That's what you get if you use:
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    optional int32 id = 1;
}

So: try adding the optional modifier.
